# How to get URL of a running app inside ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm inside `ServletContextListener`, and need to get a URL of the application in full format, including protocol, server, port, and path. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because it isn't unique. The container could have any number of aliases; it could be listening to any number of ports; and it could be listening on any specific port either HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: @yegor256 You would first have to redefine the problem, wouldn't you?