# How to get port of jetty server in java application

Tags: java, server, servletcontextlistener

I am unable to get server's port right after its initialisation in context listener. I am able to get it in my servlet using HttpServerRequest.

I want it on the server startup event.
I am using jetty 9 server with java.

Comment: Do you have `ServerConnector` ?

Comment: what do you mean by getting `server's port right`. the default port for jetty is 8080

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8485582/2299040

Comment: @nafas, I am unable to cast ServletRequest to WebAppContext. i.e. the following line is causing classCastException >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>        
 WebAppContext ctx = (WebAppContext) sce.getServletContext();

Comment: @soorapadman, No I do not have ServerConnector in my implementation.

Comment: i think you dont need to cast `getServletContext`  just do `WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();`

Comment: No luck, getting this error when creating the object of WebAppContext, >>>>>>>>>>>>>> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext